# Repeat values of 1st column in a 1st row in below empty space of next row

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have an input as below from a system

```
a b c d
  h i j
  e f g

a q w e 
  r r t
  y u i

a i o p
  j k l
  t y u
```

and I need to arrange the output as

```
a b c d
a h i j
a e f g

a q w e 
a r r t
a y u i

a i o p
a j k l
a t y u
```

I have already tried with 'awk' as

```
awk -v FS="[[:space:]][[:space:]]+" -v OFS="/t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' .
```

Comment: i have edited and modified my question.

Comment: Are the field widths always fixed?

Comment: yes the width are always fixed.

Comment: You have 1 blank between fields in your sample input but your script requires 2 or more spaces between fields. Why? Your OFS is `/t` which is a forward slash followed by a letter t - is that really what you wanted or did you intend the output to be tab separated as you'd get with `OFS="\t"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following it takes care of initial space removing too.

```
awk '{value=$0~/^ /?value:$1} /^ /{sub(/^ +/,value OFS)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too.

```
awk '
{
  value=$0~/^ /?value:$1  ##Create variable named value whose value is variable value when line starts with space else it will be first field value.
}
/^ /{                     ##Checking if a line starts with space then do following.
  sub(/^ +/,value OFS)    ##Substituting initial space with variable value and OFS value in current line.
}
1                         ##Mentioning 1 here to print edited/non-edited value of current line.
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
a b c d
a h i j
a e f g

a q w e
a r r t
a y u i

a i o p
a j k l
a t y u
```

Comment: `$0~/^ /` = `/^ /`. Your sub() will fail when `value` contains `&`. It's generally bad practice to test the same thing twice (duplicate code) - you could refactor to not do that.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks sir, could you please edit my post here, will be grateful to you sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{if (/^ /) $1=val FS $1; else val=$1} 1' file
a b c d
a h i j
a e f g

a q w e
a r r t
a y u i

a i o p
a j k l
a t y u
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is tagged `linux`, I'm assuming `gawk` is available

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 2 1' -v OFS= '{if($1=="  ")$1=p; else p=$1} 1' ip.txt
```

- `FIELDWIDTHS` allows to specify width of each field
- `2` means two characters, `1` means one character and so on
- `-v OFS=` empty OFS since field separator is part of field values
- `if($1=="  ")$1=p; else p=$1` if first field is empty(meaning two spaces in this example), assign it previously stored value

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF==3{$1 = p OFS $1} NF==4{p=$1; $1=$1} 1' ip.txt
```

This will work for varying whitespace in-between input fields and format the output to use tab as field separator

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `awk` logic as below

```
awk 'a=/^ /{sub(/^[[:space:]]/,"",$0);$0=x$0}!a{x=$1}1' file
```

which should print the output as expected.

How it works?

1. The condition `a=/^ /` would return `0` for the lines that do not start with an empty field. So in those lines we backup the value of `$1` in variable `x`
2. For the lines starting with an empty field the condition would be `1`, so we strip our a single leading space from the existing line and append with the previous value of `$1` (variable `x`)

The logic is compatible in any `awk` version and independent of the number of fields present in each line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 'N;s/^\(\(\S*\s*\).*\n\)\s*\b/\1\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace the empty space at the beginning of a non-empty line with the previous lines first column and its following spaces.